# Mac server architecture and synchronization

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, rsync, mac-osx-server, synchronization

I'm currently for an reliable and robust solution to make a bidirectional synchronization for the file between two mac os x server (recent versions). The folder is a corporate architecture of approximatively 75 GB. I've considered using some scripts from Linux like [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) or [rsync](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) but they didn't sound so much reliable. My current solution is unison.

Do some of you have used a such system in enterprise environnement before? Do you know some solutions that deserves evaluation for that usage ? Should I use a distributed file system ?

Here are the requirement of our system :

- The sync needs to be made two ways
- The sync needs to be as realtime as possible
- It would be great if the sync transfers only needed data (trough vpn tunnel) to save bandwidth

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic on all [SE] sites. Please refer to the [FAQ] and [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) blog entry explaining this further.

Comment: This is not a shopping question, i'm looking for architecture solutions. The term "enterprise solution" is used for alias to "reliable and effective" solution, i'll correct my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsync is not a bad solution here, but if you are set on spending money there are some options easily found.  You may even be able to achieve this with Time Machine.  I believe OS X also has a homesync feature for syncing directories which may be of interest.

Comment: The rsync solution does not meet the realtime part of the architecture. For the easily found options It didn't seemed so easy found. For the home Sync feature, i'm gonna tale a look at it, never heard of !